# Laravel Deployment on Shared Hosting - 404 Error

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, deployment, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to deploy my laravel 5.1 application on shared hosting cpanel. But I am getting 404 error.

> 404
>
> Not Found
>
> The resource requested could not be found on this server!

To upload the project, I make a clone of project directory and uploaded it on cpanel via their FileManger. Then move the Public folder items into Public_Html.

My .htaccess file content is shown below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also changed the following lines in index.php:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/../objecsys/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../objecsys/bootstrap/app.php';
```

What could be wrong with this deployment approach?

Comment: I guess you can change document root in cPanel. Just point your domain to your app's public folder. /user/public_html/app/public

Comment: mind to share your deployment directory structure (to be sure)? if `index.php` can't find it's components it should not throw just a 404 error - so basically it's server configuration related. your `.htaccess` is fine, i assume it's the vanilla.

Comment: I would suggest using a VPS for Laravel application. It's way more efficient.

Comment: @SonuJoshi Can you guide me little bit about how to chag document root in cPanel?

Comment: @Tezla Let me take a snapshot of directory structure...

Comment: Problem solved using @SonuJoshi suggestions..

Comment: @SonuJoshi Can you write it in Answer section? So that others who face similar problem could get it... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deploying Laravel app in cPanel is quite simple(if you are deploying on add-on domain).

In cPanel, go on add-on domains and then create a new add-on domain.

By default cPanel generates document root for you in this manner:

```
public_html/mydomain.com
```

Change it to:

```
public_html/mydomain.com/MyLaravelApp/public
```

Now upload your Laravel project under `public_html/mydomain.com` directory.

It should look like this.

[image]

If you have already an add-on domain. Go to Modify add-on domain (just below Create an Addon Domain)

Click edit icon in document root column and change your domain's document root.

[image]

Answer (score 23):

this is htaccess issue

get one `.htaccess` file in root folder of your web-project.

And put the following code inside it,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

refresh the page and check it out

my problem is solved

when i upload the laravel project into the server my application just open the default route

but all of my other web route in laravel has error

the error is :404

laravel : 404 Not Found The resource requested could not be found on this server!

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. thankyou man u saved my 2 hours time. love u. no homo.

Comment: @saber tabatabaee yazdi I have the same problem bro. The only difference is that I am using laravel 8, and inside my public_html folder, I have another folder where I put my index.php. Can you please help me about this ? This is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66647560/error-404-after-migrating-laravel-8-to-a-shared-host. Thank you.

Comment: you save my live, this answer is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

try setting empty APP_URL in your `.env`

```
APP_URL=http://
```