# Laravel on Shared Hosting pages other than '/' not showing up

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5, shared-hosting

Whatsoever I put in **Route('/') Directory** seems to show up the page:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('coming-soon');
});
```

But all other routes dont seem to work. here :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('coming-soon');
});

Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('home');
});


Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('about');
});

Route::get('/portfolio', function () {
    return view('portfolio');
});

Route::get('/support', function () {
    return view('support');
});

Route::get('/contact', function () {
    return view('contact');
});

Route::get('/faq', function () {
    return view('faq');
});

Route::auth();
```

There are no controllers yet defined. Its just plain html and css files.

In Views :

I have files :

```
home.blade.php
about.blade.php
contact.blade.php
coming-soon.blade.php
faq.blade.php
support.blade.php
portfolio.blade.php

in Layouts Folder
    - app.blade.php
```

In order for the framework to work I have put all the files in public folder to root directory. That is, css, html(or blade.php files), js folder, images folder

Everything seems fine just that other url's trigger : **Error 500 - Internal Server Error** If I go to www.example.com/public/about or /home or /contact it works but then no css property applied.

How can I best place the files in Shared-Hosting for it to work.

Any Help is Appreciated!!

Comment: Check my answer here [Laravel Deployment on Shared Hosting - 404 Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630868/laravel-deployment-on-shared-hosting-404-error/34691272#34691272)

Comment: What is myLaravelApp ? I have the app files direct in public_html/example.com Should I add a folder with a LaravelApp name?

Comment: Ok. It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change

`require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';` to `require __DIR__.'/../YourProjectName/bootstrap/autoload.php';` and

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';` to `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../YourProjectName/bootstrap/app.php';`

on index.php